# What are the motivations of the Erads?

Tags: philip-k-dick, character-motivation

In Philip K. Dick's novel *Counter-Clock World*, time on Earth is flowing backwards after an event called the "Hobart Phase", so that dead people come back to life, become younger, and  "find a womb" to become unborn again.
In this context, the "Topical Library of the People" is a powerful institution whose aim seems to be the erasing of humanity's every piece of knowledge, when the time of their discoveries has "come back". This is mainly done by destroying written material.
Among this institution are dedicated agents called the "Erads", whose job is to enforce this rule.
I do not understand their motivation to do such a thing. What could it be ?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent time paradoxes.

Imagine that a book is *not* erased as time flows backwards to the point where it appears i.e. is written and published. therefore the book continues to exist before it should have, which is a reverse paradox from the normal time travel problem.

Of course, if the book "How I Constructed A Swabble From Household Parts" was erased at the right time, then time would flow *forward* again, negating the advantages this society has from the reversal of time ( the Hobart Field . . . Which , spoiler alert, is generated by Swabbles).